# Access Array and Object inside JSON

Tags: node.js, xml, get, xml2js

I call a get API which returns XML and I was to convert to JSON, but xml2js returns [Object] [Circular] and [Array] inside an Elements Array.
How can I see what's inside the elements array?

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

var convert = require('xml-js');
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", url, true, username, password);

request.withCredentials = true;

request.send();
request.onreadystatechange=(e)=>{

    var obj = convert.xml2js(request.responseText);

console.log(obj);
```

Here's the output:

```
{ declaration:
    { attributes: { version: '1.0', encoding: 'UTF-8', standalone: 'yes' } },
   elements:
     [ { type: 'element',
         name: 'model-response-list',
         attributes: [Object],
         elements: [Array] } ] }
```

Comment: `console.log(obj.elements[0].elements);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node console output by default hides deeply nested objects/arrays. 
This behavior can be avoided with:

- [console.dir](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_dir_obj_options) with specified `depth` option
- converting an object to JSON string

```
> var obj = { a: { b: { c: { d: {} } } } };

> console.log(obj);
{ a: { b: { c: [Object] } } }

> console.dir(obj, { depth: null }); // null for unlimited recursion
{ a: { b: { c: { d: {} } } } }

> console.log(JSON.stringify, null, 4); // JSON.stringify can also format input with white spaces (in this case - 4)
{
    "a": {
        "b": {
            "c": {
                "d": {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```